# How to spy on an object that is instantiated with Callable<T> arg and implements Closeable with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to figure out how to skip a non-static void method call in a unit test by using Mockito and spying on the object.

The class in question is:

```
public class CallableExecutor<T> implements Closeable {

  public CallableExecutor( String s, Callable<T> c ) {
     this.s = s;
     this.c = c;
  }

  public void methodWeAreTryingToSkip( String string ) {
     // some logic
  }

}
```

The method I am trying to unit test is:

```
public String myMethodThatIsBeingUnitTested( args ) {
   AtomicReference<String> id = new AtomicReference<>();
   try ( CallableExecutor<String> executor = new CallableExecutor<>(
      someString, () -> { id.set( someMethodCall ) );
      return id.get();
    } ) ) {
      executor.methodWeAreTryingToSkip( string );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
      // exception handling
    }
}
```

In my unit test, I have tried the code outlined below but both end up throwing Mockito errors prior to "doNothing()" line (detailed errors at the bottom):

```
CallableExecutor<String> mockExecutor = spy( new CallableExecutor<>( any(), any() ) );
doNothing().when( mockExecutor ).methodWeAreTryingToSkip( anyString() );
```

```
Callable callable = mock( Callable.class );
CallableExecutor<String> mockExecutor = spy( new CallableExecutor<>( anyString(), eq( callable ) ) );
doNothing().when( mockExecutor ).methodWeAreTryingToSkip( anyString() );
```

Errors:

```
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(any());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(any());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
spy( new CallableExecutor<>( any(), any() ) );
```

You can't do this.  You need to make an actual `CallableExecutor` object before you can spy it.  And that means passing actual values into its constructor, not passing the output of matcher methods.

The matcher methods work by manipulating an internal structure that Mockito uses to store stubbing and verification information.  That's why you can only use them during stubbing or verification.

Pass actual non-matcher arguments to the `CallableExecutor` constructor.

Comment: I replaced the any() constructor args with actual values matching the values used in the myMethodThatIsBeingUnitTested(), however, the void method is still being called. How does Mockito know that I want to spy on any CallableExecutor object instantiation?

Comment: Because a spy is actually a wrapper for the object that it's spying on.  But you call methods on the spy, not on the underlying object.  When you call a method that hasn't been stubbed, the spy just passes it on to the spied object.  When you call a stubbed method, the spy does whatever the stubbing tells it to.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. However, as I mentioned the void method is still being called even after I replaced the "any()" arguments with actual values. Do you have any insight on why that might be?

Comment: Is either the method or the class `final`?  That would do it.  Also, how do you know that the method is still being called?  Did you check it with your debugger?

Comment: They are not final and yes, I am stepping through the code with my debugger in IntelliJ

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts and your answer/advice is helpful so I will accept it

Comment: No, please, if I haven't solved your problem, then don't accept my answer.  Accepting an answer indicates that your problem is solved, and therefore deters other people from providing an answer.  If you want someone else to help you with this, then you should revoke your acceptance of my answer.

Comment: I think for the majority of people who are struggling with the same issue - your answer will help. I have refactored my code and found a workaround without having to spy on CallableExecutor. So thanks again!